# field initialization with `val myVal: (long: Long) -> Unit)` what does it means?

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda

I'm new to using Kotlin, so far seems amazing, however I don't quite understand what's going on here:

```
class MyCallbackListener(val clickListener: (myLong: Long) -> Unit){
    fun onClick(myObject: MyObjectClass) = clickListener(myObject.longField)
}
```

So, here's what I do understand:

- I am creating a class that contains a method which receives a `MyObjectClass`
- When I call `onClick(someObject)` I am actually indicating to call `clickListener(someObject.longField)`
- I should use this callback method like this:

  ```
  MyCallbackListener{ myLong ->
    //Do Something with mylong, which will be myObject.longField }
  ```
- Unit is a Kotlin type vaguely like void

However, I don't really understand the `val clickListener: (myLong: Long) -> Unit` part.

It looks like I am declaring a final field for the class which will be of type `(myLong: Long) -> Unit` but that does not make a lot of sense.

Why or how is this enabling me to pass in the lambda for the listener?

What's exactly going on here?

I come from a Java background so it could help if you could provide equivalent code, but that is not strictly necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking at is a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types).

`(myLong: Long) -> Unit` is the type of a function that takes a single Long parameter, and returns nothing useful.  — In fact, the `myLong` parameter name is irrelevant here; it could be written more simply as `(Long) -> Unit`.

(Yes, Kotlin's [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/) type is roughly equivalent to Java's `void`: it's what functions return if they don't have anything useful to return.  That's not to be confused with [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html), which is the return type for functions that never return at all, e.g. because they have an infinite loop or always throw an exception.)

So the caller has to provide a function for that parameter.  You'd typically give a [lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax), e.g.:

```
MyCallbackListener({ myLong -> println(myLong) })
```

(Note that that could be written more simply as `MyCallbackListener(){ println(it) }`, since if the last parameter is a lamdba it can be passed [outside the brackets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas), and [`it`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) is a keyword which can be used for the single parameter of a lambda.)

But you could instead give a function reference, e.g.:

```
MyCallbackListener(SomeClass::printLong)
```

Or an [anonymous function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions), e.g.:

```
MyCallbackListener(fun(myLong: Long) { println(myLong) })
```

Or even an instance of an object implementing that function.

This doesn't have an exact equivalent in Java, because Java doesn't have first-class functions; it simply implements lambdas as instances of a functional interface (one with a Single Abstract Method) that the compiler infers.  (First-class functions are more powerful and more general, though this example doesn't really demonstrate that.)

Comment: Special thanks for the many examples and explaining that the paramenter and argument naming is not strictly necessary

Comment: Just a side note, but what is referred to as an "anonymous function" here actually has a name, which is forbidden AFAIK. Real anonymous functions don't have a name (you should just put the `fun` keyword followed by the parentheses and parameter list).

Comment: @Joffrey Whoops, of course you're right!  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You understand everything correctly. In Kotlin you can pass functions/lambdas as objects and `(myLong: Long) -> Unit` is a declaration of a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types). Constructor of `MyCallbackListener` receives a function/lambda that has a single parameter of `Long` type and which does not return anything. Then, when you initialize an object of `MyCallbackListener`, you pass this lambda as shown in your example.

If you are more familiar to Java then `(myLong: Long) -> Unit` is something similar to `Function<Long, Void>` or `Consumer<Long>`.